# Bookmarks link to first page when using figures, \clearpage, \phantomsection

Tags: floats, hyperref, bookmarks

I have the following code which includes graphic files in my document and I only want these graphics in my document especially I don't want pagenumbers, toc, titles, etc. The only problem is that all bookmarks I inserted link to first page (when using `PdfLaTeX` and using `LuaTeX` they link to the last page).
I already saw many similar problems/questions but none of the solutions worked in this case.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\pagestyle{empty}

\def\inc#1{
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \vspace*{-5cm}
        \makebox[\linewidth]{
            \includegraphics[width=1.5\linewidth]{#1}
        }
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Title 1}
\foreach \n in {1,...,52}
{
    \IfFileExists{PA\n.png}{
        \inc{PA\n.png}
    }{
        %%%
    }
}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Title 2}
\foreach \n in {53,...,111}
{
    \IfFileExists{PA\n.png}{
        \inc{PA\n.png}
    }{
        %%%
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want to get page numbers, maybe you could use `fancyhdr` and define a pagestyle without page number, did you try that?

Comment: Which `bookmark`? The one generated by `\addcontentsline`?

Comment: @oxio: `\pagestyle{empty}` should do the same then, shouldn't it? ;-)

Comment: With bookmarks I mean the bookmarks in my PDF-Reader if I click them they all link to first page. (So yes the one by addcontentsline)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer exactly :P I'm used to define my own pagestyles, so I forgot about that xD

Comment: The reason is that there is no anchor for `bookmarks`

Comment: There is phantomsection as an anchor I assume.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer When I input `\section{Title}` before than the anchor is recognized but than I get the text in my document and I don't want that.

Comment: At the moment I see that the `figure` environment screws up the whole stuff. You should drop it

Comment: This was the only way to resize the images properly and place them at the right position. Thanks for your help with this I wasn't sure if I missed some trivial command, but it seems it is what I assumed something like a bug.

Comment: @Tim: As far as I can see the floating screws up the bookmarks, not setting the page counter correctly, the `[p]` option is not healthy here. Shall the image be vertically centered?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Basically I wanted to achieve that the image should fit exactly to a4paper, the height or width which doesn't fit to a4paper should be centered. The code I used works quite good for that goal.

Comment: Package `pdfpages` is the better tool for including images as pages to fit the page without using the current page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating environments for non-floating stuff is not the right choice here.
Images can be easily imported enlarged and centered on the page via package `pdfpages`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
% ...

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Title 1}
\foreach \n in {1,...,52}
{
    \IfFileExists{PA\n.png}{%
        \includepdf{PA\n.png}%
    }{}
}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section Title 2}
\foreach \n in {53,...,111}
{
    \IfFileExists{PA\n.png}{%
        \includepdf{PA\n.png}%
    }{}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfect! I didn't know that using `pdfpages` would be the proper way here because people suggested to use the floats when inserting as a page here on stackexchange.